# iOS 9.2.1 Xcode 7.2.1 UIPageControl dots are drawn on top of each other

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uikit, uipagecontrol

I've created a UIViewController in interface builder and put a UIPageControl on top of root UIView, the root UIView's background color is orange, UIPageControl has the default configuration, except number of pages is set to 5 (changing the number of pages results in the same output). There is no code associated with the controller. UIPageControl is positioned using AutoLayout to the centre of the root UIView (I also tried doing it in code without AutoLayout, produces the same results).
When I launch it there is only one dot visible at the top left corner, opening "Debug View Hierarchy" shows that all dots are drawn, but each is drawn at the same x, y positions (x = 0, y = 0).
Here is the screenshot of IB:

[image: screenshot of IB]

And the screenshot of output of "Debug View Hierarchy":

[image]

Comment: I see five dots, what's the problem?

Comment: You see five dots on top of each other, they overlay each other, and are not visible, the "Debug View Hierarchy" screenshot shows a view from perspective showing the z-positions of views. @matt. Can you please try to do the same on your machine and see if it's the same?

Comment: Can you post your example project? That way I can examine what _you're_ doing. It just needs to have this one view controller obviously

Comment: @matt okay, I've just created a new project with the same view controller, but it turned out to be working fine, looks like something is wrong with my project. I'm trying to find out what exactly. Thank you.

Comment: :) Exactly - making a new project is a key debugging technique, because that way you see whether something else is causing the problem.

Comment: @matt thank you so much the problem was in my UIView Extensions. Still have no idea why that was causing it :-). I've added the solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in UIViewExtension, as it turns out you should not extend "origin":

```
extension UIView {
  var origin: CGPoint {
    get {
      return frame.origin
    }
    set {
      frame.origin = origin
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you @binchik . Client noticed UIPageController no longer worked and I hadn't touched the code in this area at all.  I had bought in a very similar extension 1 month prior.